# Submit value of field to database based on checkbox selection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller

I have a project where I have one field that currently adds its contents to one field in my database with the name Total. What I would like to do is be able to submit the input to two fields (which is easy enough), but on the rare occasion, I would like it to default the second field (balance) to 0.

So, at the current moment, here is a portion of my controller:

```
    $shipment->noCharge = request('noCharge');
    $shipment->noSettle = request('noSettle');
    $shipment->Total = request('Total');
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
    $shipment->noCharge = request('noCharge');
    $shipment->noSettle = request('noSettle');
    $shipment->Total = request('Total');
    $shipment->Balance = 
      //if (request('noCharge') = 1)
      // 0.00
      //else if (request('noSettle') = 1)
      // 0.00
      //else
       request('Total');
      //
```

Obviously my above won't work, but I hope it properly portrays what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply do with one variable

```
$shipment->noCharge = request('noCharge');
$shipment->noSettle = request('noSettle');
$shipment->Total = request('Total');
if ((request('noCharge') == 1) || (request('noSettle') == 1)){
   $balance = 0.00;
}else{
   $balance = request('Total');
}
$shipment->Balance = $balance;
```

OR with ternary operator

Answer (score 0):

are you hinting at something like this?

```
 $shipment->noCharge = request('noCharge');
    $shipment->noSettle = request('noSettle');
    $shipment->Total = request('Total');
      if (request('noCharge') == 1) {
        $shipment->Balance = 0.00;
      }else if (request('noSettle') == 1) {
        $shipment->Balance = 0.00; 
      }else {
        $shipment->Balance = request('Total');
      }
```